# Impossible integral? $ \int \sqrt{1-x^2} \arccos ( \sqrt{1-x^2} ) dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it possible to solve this integral?

$$ \int  \sqrt{1-x^2} \arccos ( \sqrt{1-x^2} ) dx $$

Comment: Not sure. It might be possible with $\arccos\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$ instead of $\arccos(1-x^2).$

Comment: integrate by parts to make arccos disappear.

Comment: Try letting $x=\sin\theta$.

Comment: Why don't you type it into Wolfram Alpha?

Answer (score 4):

Note $ \arccos ( \sqrt{1-x^2} )=\arcsin x$.

Then, with $t = \arcsin x$,

$$ \int  \sqrt{1-x^2} \arccos ( \sqrt{1-x^2} ) dx =\int  \sqrt{1-x^2} \arcsin x\> dx$$
$$=\int  t\cos^2t dt  =\frac12\int  t(1+\cos 2t) dt 
= \frac14t^2 +\frac14\int t d(\sin 2t) $$
$$= \frac14t^2 + \frac14t\sin2t+\frac18\cos2t+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\cos\theta = \sqrt{1-x^2}$.  This yields $-\sin\theta d\theta = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = -\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}dx$ so therefore $dx = \cos\theta d\theta$.  The integral transforms to

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\arccos\left (\sqrt{1-x^2}\right )dx & = & \int \cos(\theta)\cdot \theta \cdot \cos\theta d\theta \\
& = & \int \theta \cos^2\theta d\theta \\
& = & \int \frac{\theta}{2}(1+\cos(2\theta)) d\theta \\
& = & \frac{1}{4}\theta^2 + \frac{1}{4}\theta\sin(2\theta) - \frac{1}{4}\int \sin(2\theta)d\theta \\
& = & \frac{1}{4}\theta^2 + \frac{1}{4}\theta\sin(2\theta) + \frac{1}{8}\cos(2\theta) + C \\
& = & \frac{1}{4}\theta^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta + \frac{1}{8}\cos^2\theta - \frac{1}{8}\sin^2\theta + C \\
& = & \frac{1}{4}\left (\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}\right )^2 + \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1-x^2} -\frac{1}{4}x^2 + \frac{1}{8} +C.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I believe the factor $\sin\theta $ in the integrand is wrong.

Comment: @user I think $\sin \theta$ was introduced when Mnifldz used integration by substitution. Note the variable change from $x$ to $\theta$.

Comment: @Jam His substitution is essentially $x=\sin\theta $. Check what it gives.

Comment: This answer is incorrect anyway as the graph is the wrong shape. Its slope should be shallowing as $x\to 1$ but instead, it's becoming steeper.

Comment: @user Agreed. The $\sin$ term is superfluous and your integrand is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I did this problem quickly and made a mistake in my initial substitution.  Fixing this now.